# Fancybox change mouseover to mouseclick to change the bigger picture?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, mouseover

I'm trying to build a picture gallery with 4 small pictures and one big picture. As it is today when I do mouseover on the smaller pictures the bigger picture changes and when I click the smaller pictures I get a big floating image gallery. But when I want to change the mouseover funktion to mouseclick instead. So when I mouseclick a small picture it changes the big picture instead of making a floating one. I then have to mouseclick the bigger picture to get a floating image. Is there a way to do this? I've tried to think of ways but havnt found any?

/Pete

Comment: where is the code you have tried? (or at least what you have today)... or just looking for a recipe?

Comment: It's running in a prestashop simular to this.
http://demo-store.prestashop.com/en/evening-dresses/27-visconti-co-evening-dress.html

I don´t have the shop up and runnig yet. 

I'm not a programmer so yes I'm looking for a recipe to fix it.

Thanks,

/Pete

Answer (score 0):

Recipe.

You have to do three things :

1). remove the *class* `thickbox` from all the `<a>` tags inside the `<div id="thumbs_list">` ... so fancybox won't be launched.

2). edit the file http://demo-store.prestashop.com/themes/prestashop_new/js/product.js

Look for the line **424**, where it says

```
//hover 'other views' images management
  $('#views_block li a').hover(
     function(){displayImage($(this));},
     function(){}
  );
```

... and replace it by

```
  $('#views_block li a').click(function(){
     displayImage($(this));
  });
```

3). [accept this answers if applicable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) ;)

Comment: ... or hire a developer (programmer) otherwise ;)